# TFS upgrade ERROR: TF400255: The SQL instance MSSQLSERVER does not exist on the local machine

Tags: sql, windows, tfs, tfsbuild

I'm new to TFS, can anyone help with this?  I upgraded TFS from 2013 update 3 to update 5. The error says it can't find `MSSQLSERVER` instance but MSSQLSERVER services is running.

Log output:

> +-+-+-+-+-| Running SqlIsRunning: Verifying that SQL instance is running if local |+-+-+-+-+-
> [Info   @00:51:59.719]
> [Info   @00:51:59.719] +-+-+-+-+-| Verifying that SQL instance is running if local |+-+-+-+-+-
> [Info   @00:51:59.719] Starting Node: VSQLISRUNNING
> [Info   @00:51:59.719] NodePath : VINPUTS/Conditional/Progress/VRSINSTANCEVRSION/VSQLISRUNNING
> [Info   @00:51:59.720] Node returned: Error
> [Error  @00:51:59.720] TF400255: The SQL instance MSSQLSERVER does not exist on the local machine.
> [Info   @00:51:59.720] Completed SqlIsRunning: Error

[image]

Comment: You write `MSSQLSEVER services is running`, which is not the same as `MSSQLSERVER`. Count the number of letters in each, and then see if you can figure out which one is missing.

Comment: definitely a spelling error, it should be "MSSQLSERVER service running"

Comment: It's your responsibility to provide accurate information when asking us for help. Instead of retyping, copy/paste the error message. If you're unable to do that, then read your typed message very carefully to insure you don't introduce new errors or problems. And if it's a typo, then [edit] to correct it instead of saying so in a comment.

Comment: Point taken Ken. Thanks Leo for the edit.

Comment: @TimVo, Are your SQL server and your TFS server installed on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, they are both on the same machine. I'm running an upgrade from TFS 2013 update 3 to TFS 2013 update 5. Installation went fine but during application tier configuration I get the error.

Comment: The instance that runs under the "internal" `MSSQLSERVER` name is the **default, unnamed** instance. When you want to connect to it, you must not include the instance name in the connection string - just your machine name, or IP address (or `.` or `(local)`, if referring to the current local machine).

Comment: @TimVo, How did you upgrade your TFS 2013? What document did you update based on? Are there specific steps? You could try to check this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/server/same-app-tier-hardware?view=azure-devops-2020

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for you help. Apparently when I specified the Server in "DATABASES", I also have to specify the port (SERVER,port). Oddly enough with just specifying the server name and clicking on "test", the connection checks out. Nevertheless the verify portion went through.